# Click open nested unordered HTML list(drop-down menu) using Python and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to click open navigation bar element ("Residential Detached") shown here: [image]

Here's the HTML behind this element:

```
<div id="app_banner_menu">
   <ul class="AspNet-Menu">
      <li><a data-bind="" url="/ParagonLS/Home/Page.mvc" tabDescription="Home" subTabDescription="" subTabMaxAllowed="0" targetEx="" rel="" subTabGroup="false" subTabGroupAdd="false" subTabStartIndex="" subTabGroupClose="false" fullWindow="False" hideAddressBar="False"><span id="home-nav" class="MenuIcons homeButton"></span></a></li>
      <li>
         <span id="search-nav" class="MenuIcons searchButton"></span>
         <div>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  Search By Class
                  <ul>
                     <li><a data-bind="" url="/ParagonLS/Search/Property.mvc/Index/1" tabDescription="Residential Detached" subTabDescription="Criteria" subTabMaxAllowed="3" targetEx="" rel="" class=" SearchByClass1 " subTabGroup="true" subTabGroupAdd="true" subTabStartIndex="0" subTabGroupClose="true" fullWindow="False" hideAddressBar="False">Residential Detached</a></li>
                     <li><a data-bind="" url="/ParagonLS/Search/Property.mvc/Index/2" tabDescription="Residential Attached" subTabDescription="Criteria" subTabMaxAllowed="3" targetEx="" rel="" class=" SearchByClass2 " subTabGroup="true" subTabGroupAdd="true" subTabStartIndex="0" subTabGroupClose="true" fullWindow="False" hideAddressBar="False">Residential Attached</a></li>
```

This is the code I wrote to accomplish the same, but it doesn't work.

`resedential_detached_class = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Residential Detached')]").click()`

How can I pick just that element and click open it? It will lead me to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this selenium tag:

resedential_detached_class = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Residential Detached').click()